# How can I brighten the screen when opening an Activity in my Glass GDK immersion application?

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

I have a GDK immersion application, where the launcher `Activity` acquires a`SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK WakeLock`.  The app also has a Service which will receive chat messages and starts an `Intent` for an `Activity` to display each one.  Whenever the message `Activity` is opened, I want to brighten the screen.  However, all of the methods I have found do not seem to work.

For example, adding the following into `onResume` has no effect:

```
    Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE, SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_MANUAL);

    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
    lp.screenBrightness = 1.0f;
    getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

To better illustrate the problem, here is the sequence of events in my app:

1. Activity A starts and acquires a SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK.  Activity A dims after a short time.
2. Service B receives a chat message over the network and creates an Intent for Activity C
3. Activity C opens, sets the screen brightness as shown above, but remains dimmed

**How can I get the screen to brighten?**

Comment: The code you provided is working great for me in an activity in XE12. I was able to dim the screen, wait a second, and then reverse the dimming returning it to the previous brightness. Are you able to dim it?

Comment: @JennyMurphy In my situation, I start with Activity A, wait for it to dim, move to Activity B.  I find that Activity B won't brighten using just this code.  I did get it to work by acquiring a wakelock with the ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP flag though.  I put that code in my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to find a solution by acquiring a `SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK` with the `ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP` flag in `onResume`.  For example:

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "My Tag");
wl.acquire();
//..screen will stay on during this section..
wl.release();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to put the code before the call to `setContentView` in onCreate (the brightness level won't update otherwise), something like:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE, SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_MANUAL);

  WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
  lp.screenBrightness = 1.0f;
  getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
  // example
  setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Comment: That didn't work.  I also tried using Settings.System.putInt to change SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS to 255, but didn't have any luck.